# Simple Lightbox not scaling correctly

Tags: html, css, image, scaling

I am making a website about World Heritage Sites and wanted to make a dynamic gallery website using [simple lightbox](https://simplelightbox.com/).

It was going great then I decided that the website would look better if I would scale up the entire website using

`<body class="entire-webpage"></body>`
then using
`.entire-webpage{zoom:175%;}` for the css.

However, then the images once clicked do not scale correctly and I can only see the top left quarter. [image: Gallery image not working]

I am using the css provided from the website [Simple Lightbox](https://simplelightbox.com/) so I am not sure what part of the css I am supposed to change.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you're using zoom here?

If you're looking to increase font size, I you could just increase the font relatively using rem.

```
body {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

which gives a similar effect without scaling anything structurally. (Remember to remove both the zoom class from body and from .sl-wrapper)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a live link you can give us? Or are you developing locally?

It's a batch more complex but you'd be better scaling up content using things individually instead of zoom, as that doesn't always play as nice in the sandpit.

You can reverse the zoom on the lightbox by countering the initial zoom with:

```
.sl-wrapper {
  zoom: 58%;
}
```

but it's not going to be exact, and zooming the body may give you other issues.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, here is the url to the [site](https://projectspace.nz/cicrpuiy/World_Hertiage_Sites/)

Comment: the zoom seems to work, thank you. 
I am perfectly happy with the image showing like this.